# Postgres key(keyId, keyId, keyId)=(2, 2, 2) is not present in table constraint

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

When I start to seed my database everything is fine, but when I try to add second bunch of offers to 2nd Listing of same user (1st bunch of offers successfully added to 1st Listing of user)

**/entity/User.ts**

```
@Entity('users') // @note for postgres naming conflict
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number

  @Column({ type: 'text', unique: true })
  username: string

  @OneToMany(() => Listing, listing => listing.user)
  listings: Listing[]
}
```

**/entity/Listing.ts**    User => 1:M => Listing

```
@Entity()
export class Listing extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  title: string

  @OneToMany(() => Offer, offer => offer.listing)
  offers: Offer[]

  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: number

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.listings)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
  user: Promise<User>
}
```

**/entity/Offer.ts**    Listing => 1:M => Offer

```
@Entity()
export class Offer extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number

  @Column('int') price: number

  @PrimaryColumn()
  listingId: number

  @ManyToOne(() => Listing, listing => listing.offers)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'listingId' })
  listing: Promise<Listing>
}
```

Here is peace of code for seeding db:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: faker.internet.userName(),
  }
]

const listings = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    userId: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
    userId: 1,
  }
]

const offers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: faker.random.number(priceOptions),
    listingId: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: faker.random.number(priceOptions),
    listingId: 2,
  }
]

export const startSeeding = async () => {
    await users.map(user => User.create(user).save())

    await listings.map(listing => Listing.create(listing).save())

    setTimeout(async () => {
      await offers.map(offer => Offer.create(offer).save())
    }, 3000) // for sure
}
```

Error message:

```
query failed: INSERT INTO "offer"("price", "wage", "hoursOfWeek", "housing", "tips", "overtimes", "notes", "offerTypeId", "positionId", "listingId") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id", "housing", "tips", "overtimes" -- PARAMETERS: [256,16,32,true,true,true,"Qui dolores assumenda doloremque doloribus.",1,2,2]
error: { error: insert or update on table "offer" violates foreign key constraint "FK_d33dccabb2f699c92920ff197c8"
detail: 'Key (listingId, listingId, listingId)=(2, 2, 2) is not present in table "listing".',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is the problem with my code, I used `PrimaryColumn` for 1:M relationships, but I need just a `Column`

Answer (score 2):

```
 await users.map(user => User.create(user).save())
```

is wrong

you should do

```
 await Promise.all(users.map(user => User.create(user).save()))
```

Comment: Thank you, I replace it everywhere with my code above, but it is still same error (bunch of offers to 1st Listing is fine, however 2nd pack is failed). I put setTimer, went to postgres and it shows me that all my 2 Listings were created(with 1 and 2 IDes). Then time is up and offer which refer to 2nd Listing failed again.